# Broadcast ARP response - will dropping it cause problems?

Tags: network-protocols, wireless, arp

Are there common machines or OSs that will have problems connecting on a network where unicast ARP requests or broadcast ARP responses are not supported? I am providing a public Wi-Fi service, and considering blocking these types of ARP packet. Will this cause connectivity issues for contemporary clients?

Answer (score 1):

The ARP specification has recently been updated with [RFC 5227](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup/5227) which talks about the use of gratuitous ARP packets for "address conflict detection".

If you block ARP response broadcasts this ACD is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast ARP is used by some High-Availability IP-Takeover schemes to announce the new MAC-address on switch-over.

Comment: very true, but probably not relevant for a wifi access point.